# Getting this error with sql, "not a valid month"

Tags: sql

Here is table:

```
create table employees (emp_id number(10), emp_name char(10), hire_date varchar2(50), salary varchar(50))

insert into employees (emp_id, emp_name, hire_date, salary) values (1, 'Ramesh', '12-JAN-1998', 5000.00)
insert into employees (emp_id, emp_name, hire_date, salary) values (2, 'Suresh', '02-MAR-1997', 5500.00)
insert into employees (emp_id, emp_name, hire_date, salary) values (3, 'Kaushik', '19-JUN-1999', 5000.00)
insert into employees (emp_id, emp_name, hire_date, salary) values (4, 'Mohan', '05-AUG-2001', 6500.00)

select * from employees
```

Program to check bonus for employees with employee id:

```
Declare
    bonus number(6,2);
    emp_id number(6);
    hiredate date;

Begin
    select hire_date into hiredate from employees where emp_id = 3;
    
    if hiredate > to_date('01-jan-1998', 'DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') then
        bonus := 500;
    elsif hiredate > to_date('01-jan-1996','DD-MON-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') then
        bonus := 1000;
    else bonus := 1500;
    end if;

    dbms_output.put_line('Bonus for employee with ID ' || emp_id || ' is: ' || bonus );

End;
/
```

When I run this, it gives an error that says not a valid month. I tried digging into google and oracle but I think I did write the format mask correctly for the to_date function to convert a string into date format. But IDK what got wrong in the end.

Comment: **NEVER**, ever store DATE values in a `varchar` column. That error is the reason for the problem you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others commented on your question, You **should never** store date as varchar. You can solve your problem in this way:

```
    Declare
        bonus number(6,2);
        emp_id number(6);
        hiredate varchar2(50);
    
    Begin
        select hire_date into hiredate from employees where emp_id = 3;
        
        if to_date(hiredate,'DD-MON-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') > to_date('01-jan-1998', 'DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') then
            bonus := 500;
        elsif to_date(hiredate ,'DD-MON-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') > to_date('01-jan-1996','DD-MON-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') then
            bonus := 1000;
        else 
             bonus := 1500;
        end if;
    
        dbms_output.put_line('Bonus for employee with ID ' || emp_id || ' is: ' || bonus );
    
    End;
```

**Update: new solution.**

Also, you can do it in this way:

```
drop table employees;

create table employees (emp_id number(10), emp_name char(10), hire_date date, salary varchar(50));

insert into employees (emp_id, emp_name, hire_date, salary) values (1, 'Ramesh',  to_date('12-JAN-1998','DD-MON-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American'), 5000.00);
insert into employees (emp_id, emp_name, hire_date, salary) values (2, 'Suresh', to_date('02-MAR-1997','DD-MON-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American'), 5500.00);
insert into employees (emp_id, emp_name, hire_date, salary) values (3, 'Kaushik', to_date('19-JUN-1999','DD-MON-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American'), 5000.00);
insert into employees (emp_id, emp_name, hire_date, salary) values (4, 'Mohan', to_date('05-AUG-2001','DD-MON-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American'), 6500.00);

Declare
    bonus number(6,2);
    emp_id number(6);
    hiredate date;

Begin
    select hire_date into hiredate from employees where emp_id = 3;
    
    if hiredate > to_date('01-jan-1998', 'DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') then
        bonus := 500;
    elsif hiredate > to_date('01-jan-1996','DD-MON-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') then
        bonus := 1000;
    else bonus := 1500;
    end if;

    dbms_output.put_line('Bonus for employee with ID ' || emp_id || ' is: ' || bonus );

End;
```

and result will be:

[image]

Comment: This still returns the same error as before. Any alternative solution?

Comment: I added another solution to your question @MilindGoel